# Time format in MySql database

Tags: mysql, csv, time

In the table `theGlobal` from `MySql` Database I have the field `theTime` set on `char 50` and the field `theType` set on `char 1`.

On table `theGlobal` import with [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) two different `.csv` files.

In the first `.csv` file I have this row:

```
"T","0:01"
"B","1:05"
```

The format of **0:01** and **1:05** is `mm:ss`

In the second `.csv` file I have this row:

```
"L","00:07:10"
"L","01:21:39"
```

The format of **00:07:10** and **01:21:39** is `hh:mm:ss`

The result of import in the table `theGlobal` transform the `mm` of first `.csv` on the `hh` and the `ss` of first `.csv` on the `mm`.

E.g:

```
+---------+----------+
| theType | theTime  |
+---------+----------+
| B       | 1:05:00  |
| T       | 0:01:00  |
| L       | 00:07:10 |
| L       | 01:21:39 |
+---------+----------+
```

I need for all rows in the field `theTime` the format `hh:mm:ss`.

```
+---------+----------+
| theType | theTime  |
+---------+----------+
| B       | 00:01:05 |
| B       | 00:00:01 |
| L       | 00:07:10 |
| L       | 01:21:39 |
+---------+----------+
```

How to resolve this?

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: why u save dates in your database in Char type?

Comment: @IkaPkhakadze tanhk you now store the data in a time column, not varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loading the data, you can assign it to a variable first, then do whatever with the variable and load it in the actual column. In your case this would look something like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE t1
(column1, @var1)
SET column2 = TIME(STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%i:%S'));
```

Adjust the `STR_TO_DATE()` parameter as needed. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)'s a table explaining it (it's for `date_format()` but it's the same for `str_to_date()`).

Oh, and store the data in a `time` column, not `varchar`.